# Strange network and graphics card behavior

Tags: networking, graphics-card

I'm facing strange issues with my network and graphics cards.

My computer's specs:

- OMEN by HP 17-w008ng
- Intel Core i7-6700HQ 4x 2.60 GHz
- 16GB DDR4 RAM PC4 17000 (2133 MHz)
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 965M (4GB GDDR5) + Intel HD Graphics 530
- Network adapter only says "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller" in the Device Manager (but it is capable of taking 1000MBit/s speed)
- My OS is Windows 10 Pro
- NVIDIA Graphics Card driver (as of 2018-02-17) 390.77 from 2018-01-29
- Network driver is at version 22.20.16.4749 (from 2017-07-24)

I recently updated my cable speed to 500MBit/s but when performing speed tests I always only got 100MBit/s download max (at 50MBit/s up). Looking at my router there are 2 LEDs, a green one and an orange one for every LAN slot. Eventually I restarted my computer and noticed that the green LED started to glow. When I opened my router's configuration window I saw that suddenly the computer was connected at 1000MBit/s and running a speed test showed that I had a download of 500MBit/s. When sometime I had to restart my computer again the behaviour switched again and I got back to 100MBit/s max to the router. Could there be a software problem?

A similar behaviour happens to my graphics card when playing games - sometimes when I start a game everything runs absolutely smoothly (I'm talking about 60+ FPS in DOOM (yep, I'm talking about the newest one) on an Ultra configuration or 50+ FPS in The Witcher 3 on Ultra etc.) but then when I restart my PC or shut it down and turn it on again when I'm trying to start a game I'm only running at 10- FPS in most of the games.

I haven't yet checked if there's a connection to DirectX or OpenGL games but I at least tried it for The Witcher 3 (which should run with DirectX) and DOOM (which I configured to run with Vulkan) which gives me the same behaviour.

I'm starting to despair. I tried reinstalling the network and graphics drivers and updating chipset drivers with no success. Can anyone help me?

I got a feeling that this should be a software problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A gigabit connection falling back to 100mbit could be related to driver issues, hardware issues or cable issues (gigabit uses 8 wires in your cable whereas 100mbit only uses 4 so a loose connection can cause a fallback to 100mbit).

Please try the following things:

1. Update the driver of your network card to the latest available from the manufacturer
2. Try a different cable
3. Go to device manager, right click your network card and select properties. Here, go to the advanced tab and try forcing the speed to 1000mbit instead of having auto negotiation enabled.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I'll give it a shot and try some different cables to see if it changes something. the network card driver is the newest one so I guess the cable is the only bottleneck that's left.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still struggling with the graphics card issue. Is it possible that Windows just decides randomly which card is to be used (or let's say maybe based on some strange factors) for normal usage every time the OS starts?